# Why do I get unwanted animation when adding a subview to my scrollview?

Tags: ios, animation, uiscrollview

I'm working on a document viewer app, based on the PhotoScroller example from Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html).

I react to the zoom and scroll events to load new pages that come into view, and old pages are recycled to reduce the overhead of creating new ones.

I also have an automatic zoom in the app (through `zoomToRect` or by setting the `contentOffset`). Inside the handler for the zoom and scroll events, I add new pages as needed:

```
[self configurePage:page forIndex:index]; //sets frame, loads image,...
[self.scrolledView addSubview:page];
```

What surprises me is that sometimes I see a page flying through the screen from left to right. With some logging, I have made sure that it is a new page (never used before).

How can this happen? And how could I prevent it?

Looking forward to your tips....

ETA: When the app zooms into a page I do that with `[UIScrollView zoomToRect:animate:NO]` inside the `[UIView animateWithDuration: ...]` block to have control over the animation speed.

I now have the behavior as I want it by configuring and adding all pages that will be visible during the animation and starting the animation with `[UIView animateWithDuration: ...]` only afterwards.

Still it surprises me that calling `[self.scrolledView addSubview:page];` inside the zoom and scroll event handlers can lead to an animation. If anyone has a clue how to prevent that in a cleaner way, please let me know.

Comment: are you using autolayout? and are you animating anything with UIView.animate.. ?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I'm not using auto layout and the only animations I have use [UIScrollView zoomToRect:animate:NO] inside the UIView animateWithDuration: ....

Comment: do you use interface builder to set things up or do you do it programatically?

Comment: @Erik, it is all done programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

If the `animateWithDuration:...` call is on the stack, anything you do that is animatable will be animated.  Set a breakpoint on your `addSubview:` call and see what's up the stack.

You can also try this:

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{        // Note: available since iOS7.
    [self.scrolledView addSubview:page];
}];
```